# How can I get fill color of sprite?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm randomly creating circles on stage and listening for clicks on the circles. When I click a circle, I want to trace the circle's fill color. How can I get this data?

This is what I'm using to create the circle:

```
// create the circle
var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
circle.graphics.clear();
var circleColor = randomColor();
circle.graphics.beginFill(circleColor, 1);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleRadius);
circle.graphics.endFill();
```

And the function that fires when a circle is clicked:

```
private function clickCircle(event:MouseEvent): void {
    var currentCircleName = event.currentTarget.name;

    // hide the circle
    event.currentTarget.visible = false;

    // update stats
    clickCount++;
    txt_clicksCount.text = String(clickCount);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I discovered that you cannot add data to a sprite via this [question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249113/store-variable-in-movieclip-or-sprite).

What I decided to do was create a new class that extends Sprite.

```
package  {
   import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class altSprite extends Sprite {
        public var color:String;
    }
}
```

So now I changed my Sprite call to:

```
var circle:altSprite = new altSprite();
```

And store the color to this altSprite by doing:

```
circle.color = circleColor;
```

And I can call this color in my function:

```
trace(event.currentTarget.color);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the following link and use the method called:

```
readGraphicsData()
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData

You'll need Flash Player 11.6, AIR 3.6

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. While this does help, I believe the flash player version might be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Your posted solution seems more scalable and easy to achieve. Happy coding:)