# Moving MovieClips' timeline along a frame only the FIRST TIME a button is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a little AS3 game and am a bit stuck.

I am trying to use a button to 'advance' or rather, move the focus along the timeline within a separate, root level MovieClip ('score_mc') ... e.g. frame one to two, two to three etc.

However, I have 25 MovieClips which have buttons in them - but I ONLY want those buttons to be able to effect the 'score_mc' once. So, effectively, I want to 'lock out' the 'advance' effect after it's been done once per button click.

ps I need to be able to use the buttons over and over again, but only effecting the 'score_mc' the first time each one is used.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: show your current relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting a boolean var to do this for each button? something like `firstClick = true` at instantiation, but flipping it to `false` in the `onPress` method?

Something like:

```
function click_handler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (this.firstClick) {
        score_mc.nextFrame();
        this.firstClick = false;
    }
}
my_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_handler);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems nice and simple, I think. I'll try to implement and let you know how I go!...

Comment: Can I be a real pest and ask how then, my script would look if I applied that?:

Comment: ____

linkbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickNextSlide1);

function onClickNextSlide1(event:MouseEvent):void

{

 // reset this circle 
 Object(root).all_int_circles_master.cone.gotoAndStop("off");
 
 // change circle 'state' of current circle
 Object(root).all_int_circles_master.cone.circle_states.gotoAndPlay("linked");
 
 //target next circle / YOU start position
 Object(root).all_int_circles_master.cten.gotoAndPlay("sw"); 
 
 // change circle 'state' of NEXT circle
 Object(root).all_int_circles_master.cten.circle_states.gotoAndPlay("live");
 

____

Comment: If all the buttons are in an array, you can just loop through the array twice, first setting the `firstClick` property to `true`, then assigning th click handler to that button. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1249124/555558 for inspiration.

Comment: No need for a variable per button, simply remove the listener in the handler function.

Comment: I tried jayands approach but got a bit lost. I managed to achieve what I required by using the .nextFrame command you mention though! Thanks.

I created 25 movie clips (identical, different instance names) and just had stop(); on every frame (100frames)...

However, only the 2nd frame has any extra as3 on it: (so, only 1 registered 'count' per each of the 25 mc's)

Object(root).counter_int.nextFrame();

Total workaround, but it does what I wanted it to. 

Ta

Answer (score 1):

Just define an array of boolean, size of 25, on the click event function, check when the array[i] == false, then forward the score_mc, and mark the 
array[i] = true